# SSL error when trying to load TLSv1.2 site in an iframe inside UIWebView

Tags: ios, ssl, iframe, uiwebview, tls1.2

I am displaying a web site in my iOS app (user's profile) that contains an option to purchase some services. The purchase is done inside the `UIWebView` by opening a third party payment page inside an `iframe`.
When trying to load this payment page, an SSL error is sent to webView:didFailLoadWithError: delegate method.

The SSL error:

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 \"An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.\" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x610000255c90 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 \"An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.\" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://SOME-URL, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://SOME-URL, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://SOME-URL, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://SOME-URL, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}

I have tested this URL in a browser and I see that it uses TLSv1.2 so I don't understand what is the problem.
The same iframe works as expected in iOS Safari and in an Android app...

When I disable ATS (NSAppTransportSecurity) in the Info.plist then the payment page is displayed, but I'm afraid that Apple won't allow it is the AppStore (and I don't want to do it - it's a payment page and it should be secure).

This is the payment URL: 
https://cgmpi.creditguard.co.il/CGMPI_Server/PerformTransaction?txId=a51270b0-9cb5-43aa-83cc-1cb0abe08691

Comment: How did you verify TLS v1.2?

Comment: It might be easier if you would provide the URL to reproduce the problem. Apart from that the problem might not be the TLS protocol version but the offered ciphers - which can be different between the browser and uiwebview

Comment: Added the payment URL. Tested the TLS version by browsing to this URL from FireFox on my Mac and checked the secured connection details...

Answer (score 0):

I would put an exception regarding the webviews, the domain and the TLS version in the Info.plist to make sure that the ATS layer won't block any connection.

Something like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>creditguard.co.il</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: I don't want to mark this domain as insecure because (1) it is a payment page and should be the most secure in the app and (2) probably Apple won't allow it in the app review.  
In addition, I have tried it and it doesn't solve the problem - only disabling ATS totally helps...